# Emiting events does not work with cross contract calling

Tags: ink, rust, events, contracts

When using cross contract calling on another contract which also emits
events the events of the original contract do not work anymore.
I get the following error.

```
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
   --> lib.rs:109:24
    |
109 |             self.env().emit_event(EventName {
    |                        ^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `C` declared on the trait `EmitEvent`
    |
note: multiple `impl`s satisfying `ink_lang::EnvAccess<'_, ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>: ink_lang::codegen::EmitEvent<_>` found
   --> lib.rs:5:1
    |
5   | #[ink::contract]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    = note: and another `impl` found in the `other_contract` crate: `impl<'a> ink_lang::codegen::EmitEvent<other_contract::OtherContract> for ink_lang::EnvAccess<'a, <other_contract::OtherContract as ink_lang::reflect::ContractEnv>::Env>;`
```

How can I cross call contracts and emit events in both of them, without them interfering with each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is known [issue](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1000), should be fixed with [refactored events](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1243).